# htaccess file has no affect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite an url like this:

> www.mywebsite.com/product/a-product-name-here/92341

to

> www.mywebsite.com/our-products/a-product-name-here/92341

I'm using following rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ our-products/$  [R=301,L]
```

And according to [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/%20this) online tool it should do the trick. I've put this online, but it didn't affect anything.

AllowOverride is active on my host.

My folder structure is like this (tried the rewrite rule in both of the 2 .htaccess's): 
[image: folder structure]

**UPDATE**

This is the .htaccess content in the folder `Corporate`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /corporate/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /corporate/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this is the content of the .htaccess file in the `product` folder:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?a=$1 [nc]
```

Comment: I guess you will need to restart apache server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /our-products/$1  [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: @anubhava didn't work. (thanks for your answer)

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: @starkeen yes, indeed.

Comment: Which URL do you want your visitors to see? `example.com/our-products/1234/` or `example.com/products/1234`? Your actual code folder is named `products`, I assume from the above image?

Comment: @JanPapenbrock the word "products" in the link should become "our-products"

Answer (score 0):

Alright, as far as I understand, your problem can be divided into two parts.

## Redirect public URL

You want the public URL `example.com/product/foo-bar/1234` to be redirected to `example.com/our-products/foo-bar/1234`. This can be achieved with the already posted rule by anubhava, slightly modified to only match numbers:

Put it in your root `.htaccess`, besides `index.php`.

```
RewriteRule ^product/((.+)/(\d+))$ /our-products/$1 [R=301,L]
```

## Map external URL to script, internally

Then, the external URL is `example.com/our-products/foo-bar/1234`, which does not physically exist on the server machine and therefore fails with a 404.

So you'll have to map it to the script containing the actual logic.

```
RewriteRule ^our-products/(.+)$ /product/index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

This is assuming that your script will accept the `a` parameter.

## Your `.htaccess` files, after the changes

This is the `.htaccess` content in the folder `Corporate`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^product/((.+)/(\d+))$ /our-products/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^our-products/(.+)$ /product/index.php?a=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /corporate/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /corporate/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this is the content of the `.htaccess` file in the product folder:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: Sow here should I put the second RewriteRule? In the same .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, exactly, somewhere below the first rule.

Comment: I still get a 404. :/

Comment: `/product/.htaccess` is empty?

Comment: `AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?a=$1 [nc]`  + your rewrite rules.

Comment: Please try putting the above rules in the _root_ .htaccess and remove the `RewriteRule` from `product/.htaccess`

Comment: I've update my question with the content of all the current .htaccess files. Which lines should I keep and which should I remove?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've updated the format of the URL in my question. (Maybe this changes something in the rewriterules?) Because your answer still isn't working atm.

Comment: Would be pretty good to have correct examples in the question, when it is posted. Updated answer again.

Comment: Still a "Page not found". :/

Comment: OK, I tried the above files in a separated dummy environment. You can find it here: https://github.com/janpapenbrock/stackoverflow-36078767. As everything works OK, another question comes up: Which URL does your WordPress have in the browser? http://example.com/corporate? If yes, then please move the rewrite rules into the actual root, i.e. to the level above /corporate. Then, move /product one level up as well.